# Parsing NumPy arrays from pandas data frame cells

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, file, parsing

I'm rather new to Pandas, and I think I have messed up with my data files.

I have stored some pandas data frames to CSV files. Data frames contained NumPy arrays stored in a single column. I know that it is not recommended to do so. However, because the arrays have an indefinite number of elements (varying row by row), I stored them in a single column. Column names and column order was getting a bit tedious otherwise. Initially, my notion was that I would not need those arrays for my data analysis because they contain raw data just stored for completeness. It was only later that I realized that I would have to go back to the raw data to extract some relevant data. Lucky for me that I saved it initially, but reading it back from the CSV files proved to be difficult.

Everything works fine, as long as I have the original data frame, but when I read the data frame back from CSV, the columns that contain the arrays are read back as strings instead of NumPy arrays.

I have used Pandas.read_csv function's converters option and NumPy.fromstring function with some regular expressions to parse the NumPy arrays from the strings. However, it is slow (data frames contain approx 400k rows).

So, preferably, I would like to convert the data once and save the data frames to a file format that maintains the NumPy arrays in the cells and can be read back directly as NumPy arrays. What would be the best file format to use if it is possible? Or what would be the best way to do it otherwise?

Your suggestions would be appreciated.

For completeness, here is my converter code:

```
def parseArray(s):
    s = re.sub(r'\[','',s)
    s = re.sub(r'\]','',s)
    s = re.sub(r' +',',',s)
    s = np.fromstring(s,sep=',')
    return s

testruns = pd.read_csv("datafiles/parse_test.csv", converters={'swarmBest': parseArray})
```

Without the converter, the `'swarmBest'` column is read back as a string:

```
'[1095.56629   52.32807    8.43377  122.19014   75.42834    8.43377]'
```

With the converter I can do for example:

```
testarray = swarmFits[0]
print(testarray)
print(testarray[0])

Output:
[1095.56629   52.32807    8.43377  122.19014   75.42834    8.43377]
1095.56629
```

Comment: Please add some clarity in terms of what you are actually asking for help on

Comment: I was asking if anyone knows a file type supported by pandas that would keep the numpy arrays as arrays when reading back from a file. Documentation doesn't talk about this kind of features and I couldn't find a solution from old questions.